# Waiting until a process is complete to execute a line of code

Tags: java, android

strReturnedAddress takes approx. 3 seconds to calculate -but it might be as fast as half a second. this line triggers the calculation

```
new GetCurrentCity().execute();
```

Right after that line comes this line

```
    if(!(strReturnedAddress == null)){
        test.setText(strReturnedAddress);
```

I want that if statement to be executed the moment strReturnedAddress is calculated.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: there is a method in the AsyncTask class called `onPostExecute`, use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the results of the execution after `doInBackGround()` , you can put the code in `onPostExecute()`. `onPostExecute` will run on the main thread and has the returning values of the `doInBackGround()` pass into the params.

Another way is to `task.execute().get()` to wait for the results. But this defeats the purpose of the [Asyntask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could change  `GetCurrentCity().execute();` into a Thread. If so, you could:

```
Thread blah= GetCurrentCity();
blah.run();
blah.join();
if(!(strReturnedAddress == null)){
    test.setText(strReturnedAddress);
}
```

But that would be self-defeating (like the comments indicate)

Comment: Like Slaks said, there's no point in using a thread if you do this.  also, you don't execute a thread, you start() it.

Comment: You're right, @GabeSechan. Still, the question seems to indicate that (s)he's using an AsyncTask wrong, isn't it?